# Incompatible pointer types from a pair of data structures in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

Compiling the code below is throwing a warning. Please let me know what's wrong with this code.

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] p2->node = p1;

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node1{
    int item;
}n1;

typedef struct node2{
    struct n1 *node;
}n2;

int main(){
    n1 *p1 = malloc(sizeof(n1));
    p1->item = 23;

    n2 *p2 = malloc(sizeof(p2));
    p2->node = p1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `struct n1` does not exist. However you have typedefed a type `n1`. Therefore you have to use that type in your other "struct".

```
typedef struct node2
{
   n1 *node;
}n2;
```

Or use the matching struct

```
typedef struct node2
{
   struct node1 *node;
}n2;
```

You are also not allocating enough memory for the struct in the second malloc call.
The size you give it is size of a pointer `sizeof(p2)` while it should be either `sizeof(*p2)`, `sizeof( struct node2 )` or `sizeof( n2 )`.

Comment: Also, `malloc(sizeof(p2))` will only allocate enough bytes to hold a pointer. You want `malloc(sizeof(n2))`

Comment: True, though in this particular case, `sizeof(n2)` will be the size of the structure since it only contains a single pointer.  However, that is very much the exception, not the rule.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Only if you're lucky.